# Check box jQuery show hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I think this is simple, but I can't find the answer. I have a check box and two div: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/398faqmr/1/).

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='All' id='All' value='All' />
 <label for='All'><small>All</small></label>

<div class="all">Ini ALL</div>
<div class="not_all" style="display:none;">Ini not ALL</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#All').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#not_all').hide(1000);
      $('#all').show(1000);
    }else{
      $('#not_all').attr('style','inline-block');
      $('#all').hide(1000);
      $('#not_all').show(1000);
    }
});
```

I want first view to be `<div class='all'>` and hidden `<div class='not_all'>`. When I `uncheck` the check box, the view is `<div class='not_all'>` and hidden `<div class='all'>`.

Comment: please edit your question to include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change "#" into "." for class selection. Your code look like below:

```
$('#All').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
         $('.not_all').hide(1000);
         $('.all').show(1000);
    }else{
         $('.not_all').attr('style','inline-block');
         $('.all').hide(1000);
         $('.not_all').show(1000);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you have given class so use `.` instead of `#` for your divs.

**note:**  `#` is used to access id and  `.` is to access class.

```js
 $('#All').on('click',function(){
     if (this.checked) {
       $('.not_all').hide(1000);
       $('.all').show(1000);
     }else{
       $('.not_all').attr('style','inline-block');
       $('.all').hide(1000);
       $('.not_all').show(1000);
     }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='All' id='All'  value='All'  />
 <label for='All'><small>All</small></label>

<div class="all">Ini ALL</div>
<div class="not_all" style="display:none;">Ini not ALL</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#All').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.not_all').delay(1000).hide();
      $('.all').show();
    }else{
      $('.not_all').attr('style','inline-block');
      $('.all').hide();
      $('.not_all').show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

divs `all` and `not_all` are defined as classes and not ids, so use `.` to address them in your code:
try this:

```
$('#All').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.not_all').hide(1000);
      $('.all').show(1000);
    }else{
      $('.not_all').css('display','inline-block'); # use css() instead of attr()
      $('.all').hide(1000);
      $('.not_all').show(1000);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/398faqmr/3/)